# Calculate $\intop_{x=0}^{1}e^{-\frac{k_{1}x}{a}}e^{-\frac{ak_{2}}{x}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)^{2}dx$

Tags: calculus

Calculate $$\displaystyle\large{\intop_{x=0}^{1}e^{-\dfrac{k_{1}x}{a}}e^{-\dfrac{ak_{2}}{x}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{x}\right)^{2}dx}.$$

I'm pretty sure this can be done in Mathematica but I'm having problems using it at the moment.

Comment: Set up a quadrature? or closed-form?

Comment: Is it enough for you to get the matlab code and the solution ?

Comment: I require the answer in closed form... if it exists.

Comment: If someone could type this into Mathematica and tell me the answer I would be ever so grateful.

Comment: Mathematica can't do it.